# rxJava Observable chain stops after onErrorResumeNext

Tags: android, rx-java

I've the following chain of observables:

```
public Observable<Void> ApiCallBackObservable() {
    return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final AsyncEmitter<Void> voidAsyncEmitter) {
            APICall.setCallBack(new CallBack() {
                @Override
                public void onResponseReceived() {
                    voidAsyncEmitter.onNext(null);
                    voidAsyncEmitter.onCompleted();
                }
            });

        }
    }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.NONE).timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<? extends Void> call(Throwable throwable) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    });

}
```

The problem is that after this API callback i'm chaining more observables:

```
apiCallBackObservable().map(new Func1<Void, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Void aVoid) {
                    return "Ok";
                }
            }).flatmap(...).flatmap(....)....;
```

but somehow when the code hits the onErrorResumeNext(because of the timeout), the chain stops it never hits the next map, no error no anything it just stops.

Comment: What do you mean it stops? You replace that error with an empty observable and thus the sequence completes.

Comment: The outcome of the ApiCallBackObservable() is Void, i was returning null on the onErrorResumeNext but that was causing a different error, that is why i tried with Observable.empty(). I didn't know Observable.empty would terminate the chain. Maybe i should just return a Boolean for ApiCallBackObservable() so i don't have to mess with Void and nulls...

Comment: yea Observable.empty  was the bad guy, thanks @akarnokd